# A simple compiler between two ASTs exposing identical language types and operations

Tags: haskell

I'm looking for an elegant way to solve the problem below. All options are welcome, particularly type classes and GADTs :-)

The scenario is this: there exists a small language with types (Strings and Ints) and operations (+, -, ++ and split). There are two syntax's for the language, each with their own parser. I'd like to write a compiler that can go either from language X to language Y, or from Y to X. Compiling from one to the other is a straight forward mapping over a list of expressions with one of these:

```
xToY :: ExpX -> ExpY
yToX :: ExpY -> ExpX
```

.. followed by a `show` over either `[ExpY]` or `[ExpX]`. Here is a naive implementation of these two compiler functions, using normal data definitions and pattern matching on constructors:

```
{-# LANGUAGE LambdaCase #-}

module Compiler where

data ExpX = StringX String | IntX Int | ArithOpX ArithExpX | StringOpX StringExpX deriving (Show)
data ArithExpX = EAddX ExpX ExpX | EMinusX ExpX ExpX deriving (Show)
data StringExpX = EAppendX ExpX ExpX | ESplitX ExpX ExpX deriving (Show)

data ExpY = StringY String | IntY Int | ArithOpY ArithExpY | StringOpY StringExpY deriving (Show)
data ArithExpY = EAddY ExpY ExpY | EMinusY ExpY ExpY deriving (Show)
data StringExpY = EAppendY ExpY ExpY | ESplitY ExpY ExpY deriving (Show)

xToY :: ExpX -> ExpY
xToY =
    \case
    StringX s -> StringY s
    IntX i -> IntY i
    ArithOpX (EAddX a b) -> ArithOpY (EAddY (xToY a) (xToY b))
    ArithOpX (EMinusX a b) -> ArithOpY (EMinusY (xToY a) (xToY b))
    StringOpX (EAppendX a b) -> StringOpY (EAppendY (xToY a) (xToY b))
    StringOpX (ESplitX a b) -> StringOpY (ESplitY (xToY a) (xToY b))

yToX :: ExpY -> ExpX
yToX =
    \case
    StringY s -> StringX s
    IntY i -> IntX i
    ArithOpY (EAddY a b) -> ArithOpX (EAddX (yToX a) (yToX b))
    ArithOpY (EMinusY a b) -> ArithOpX (EMinusX (yToX a) (yToX b))
    StringOpY (EAppendY a b) -> StringOpX (EAppendX (yToX a) (yToX b))
    StringOpY (ESplitY a b) -> StringOpX (ESplitX (yToX a) (yToX b))
```

Testing the noddy compiler:

```
*Compiler> xToY (ArithOpX (EAddX (IntX 2) (IntX 5)))
ArithOpY (EAddY (IntY 2) (IntY 5))
*Compiler> yToX (StringOpY (ESplitY (StringY "foo") (StringY "bar")))
StringOpX (ESplitX (StringX "foo") (StringX "bar"))
```

So it works. Unfortunately, there is a lot code repetition and a pattern is clearly emerging. I'd like to adopt a more elegant feature of Haskell to achieve the same result given by `xToY` and `yToX`. In particular, I'm looking for a way to define duality between constructors, for example `StringX s` gets compiled to `StringY s` whilst `StringY s` gets compiled back in to `StringX s`. Surely there's a nice way to express this? Moreover, the nested `xToY` and `yToX` calls on the right side of the case matching looks grungy, e.g. `ArithOpX (EAddX (yToX a) (yToX b))`. There must be a better way?

Comment: Your `ExpX` and `ExpY` are really some single type `Exp t` where `t` has been replaced by some type to tag it as being for a different purpose. See the tagged package for the canonical way to tag types: http://hackage.haskell.org/package/tagged.

Comment: Why not just have two parsers that both produce values of type `ExpX` (and never define `ExpY` at all)...?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try replacing `ExpX` and `ExpY` with the following single type `Exp t`.  `t` is a tag that is replaced by some type to tag it as being for a specific purpose:

```
data Exp t = String String | Int Int | ArithOp (ArithExp t) | StringOp (StringExp t) deriving (Show)
data ArithExp t = EAdd (Exp t) (Exp t) | EMinus (Exp t) (Exp t) deriving (Show)
data StringExp t = EAppend (Exp t) (Exp t) | ESplit (Exp t) (Exp t) deriving (Show)

data ForX = ForX
data ForY = ForY
```

And then use `Exp ForX` in place of `ExpX` and `Exp ForY` in place of `ExpY` everywhere you care about the difference.

You can then write functions that work `forall` tags. For example, we could replace `xToY` and `yToX` with a single function `retag`:

```
retag:: Exp t1 -> Exp t2
retag =
    \case
    String s -> String s
    Int i -> Int i
    ArithOp (EAdd a b) -> ArithOp (EAdd (retag a) (retag b))
    ArithOp (EMinus a b) -> ArithOp (EMinus (retag a) (retag b))
    StringOp (EAppend a b) -> StringOp (EAppend (retag a) (retag b))
    StringOp (ESplit a b) -> StringOp (ESplit (retag a) (retag b))
```

This type `t` is an example of a "phantom type". A "phantom type" is a type that never appears in any constructor.

Comment: As an add on, you can even use `newtype Tagged t a = Tagged { unTagged :: a }` to directly express the tag forgetting that might be easier to handle than functions polymorphic over the tag: `unTagged :: Tagged ForX Exp -> Exp`.

Comment: If you ever add constructors to your AST you will have to update `retag`. Since the types `Exp ForX` and `Exp ForY` differ only in types, you can safely write `retag :: Exp a -> Exp b; retag = Unsafe.Coerce.unsafeCoerce`. But having a `newtype Tagged` as J.Abrahamson suggested gives you the same succinctness without `unsafe`. Also it enforces the fact that a value of type `t` will never be created, which is not the case with `Exp ForX` as there could easily be a constructor `data Exp t = ... | Bad t | ...` which would break the `unsafeCoerce` implementation.